# creating new table out of excising table

Tags: sqlite

Write a query that outputs another version of the table of prerequisites, where courses are represented by their titles, not by their IDs. In the resulting table, rename the columns “course_id” and “prereq_id” to “course” and “prerequisite” respectively. Write this query without join or product.

there are my tables

### table name: course

```
course_id     | title

BIO-101   |  Intro. to Biology  

BIO-301    | Genetics   

BIO-399    | Computational Biology  

CS-101      |  Intro. to Computer Science   

CS-190      | Game Design   

CS-315      | Robotics  

CS-319      | Image Processing  

CS-347     | Database System Concepts   

EE-181    |  Intro. to Digital Systems  

FIN-201   |  Investment Banking 

HIS-351   |  World History  

MU-199    |  Music Video Production

PHY-101   |  Physical Principles
```

---

### table name: prereq

```
course_id   | prereq_id

BIO-301      |   BIO-101

BIO-399 |   BIO-101

CS-190  |   CS-101

CS-315  |   CS-101

CS-319  |   CS-101

CS-347  |   CS-101

EE-181  |   PHY-101
```

### my code

//just gives me intro to bio for all the prereq's

```
select title,(

  select title

  from course as C

  where course_id = (

  select prereq_id

  from prereq as P

  where C.course_id = P.prereq_id)) as prereq

from course as C

where course_id = (

  select course_id

  from prereq as P

  where C.course_id = P.course_id)
```

//this is using product

```
select c.title, (

  select title 

  from course as q 

  where q.course_id = p.prereq_id) as title2

from course as c, prereq as p

where c.course_id = p.course_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without joins is the worst choice, but I guess this is homework, so:

```
select 
  (select title from course where course_id = p.course_id) as course,
  (select title from course where course_id = p.prereq_id) as prerequisite
from prereq as p
```

Each subquery fetches the title from `course`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kfnpRuW1RCYfm8zWmqqZTt/0).
Results:

```
| course                    | prerequisite               |
| ------------------------- | -------------------------- |
| Genetics                  | Intro. to Biology          |
| Computational Biology     | Intro. to Biology          |
| Game Design               | Intro. to Computer Science |
| Robotics                  | Intro. to Computer Science |
| Image Processing          | Intro. to Computer Science |
| Database System Concepts  | Intro. to Computer Science |
| Intro. to Digital Systems | Physical Principles        |
```